# Behat using BeforeScenario vs Given

Tags: behat, mink

For something that REALLY needs to be set up before every scenario then BeforeScenario is used.

Sometimes there are things that only need to be set up for some scenarios, but for a significant proportion of them. For example, if the scenario needs a "regular user account" to exist, then it goes on to login as that user and do some stuff.

You can make an @BeforeScenario @RegularUser method that will run for each Scenario tagged as @RegularUser. So scenarios end up looking like:

```
@RegularUser
Scenario login as a regular user
  Given I am on the login page
  When I login to a regular user account
  Then the welcome screen is displayed
```

The alternative is to

```
Scenario login as a regular user
  Given a regular user exists
  And I am on the login page
  When I login to a regular user account
  Then the welcome screen is displayed
```

"a regular user exists" would be associated with the method that creates the regular user.

With the first approach, I can make @AfterScenario @RegularUser that will delete the user after the scenario ends. So that seems "a good thing".

But the 2nd approach kind of looks nicer to me from a BDD viewpoint. But its limitation is that then there is nothing happening at the end of the scenario to delete the user.

Which approach is the better practice?

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, i would go with first option.

The problem is that, both options are not so good, because normally you have context of this scenario added:

```
In order to ..
As a Regular User 
I need to ..
```

That should show what was you intention of running this scenario. The process of creating **RegularUser** don't adding value to scenario itself.

Then, if you need to confirmation in scenario of having regular user - then is OK. But in here in my opinion, it is not the point - then second option is not so good - we have context to add informations like that.

That is why, I think first option (not ideal, but better that second) is good solution.

I don't know in Behat functionality to set up user by context, but tag option should be more elastic.